# If window size is mobile and form is visible do not run script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to cancel this script if two conditions are met:

1. window width is 767 or less
2. `#hidden-form` has style of display: block

Here is the function:

```js
function init() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
      shrinkOn = 300,
      header = document.querySelector("header");
    if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
      classie.add(header, "smaller");
    } else {
      classie.remove(header, "smaller");
    }
  });
}
window.onload = init();
```

I tried adding the following as an else if but it canceled the script in all views:

```js
{
  ($(window).width() <= 767 && $('#hidden-form').css('display', 'block')) {
    .return;
  }
```

Updated code but not working -----

```
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || 
document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 300,
            header = document.querySelector("header");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header, "smaller");

        } else if  ( $(window).width() <= 767 && $('#hidden-form').css('display') == 'block' ) {
.return;
} else {

            classie.remove(header, "smaller");

        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
```

Unfortunately, this still isnt working, any ideas?

Comment: FYI `.css('display')` returns a value while `.css('display','block')` sets a value.

Comment: @epascarello can you please explain? The function is working fine until I try to add this conditional, what is wrong with window.onload = init(); ?

Comment: because you are calling the function and running it.  It is not waiting for load. It should be `window.onload = init;`

Comment: And you have `.return;` <-- what is with the `.` before the return?

Comment: Thanks @epascarello! The "." was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
$('#hidden-form').css('display') == 'block'
```

Also, for mobile check, you can use [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

Answer (score 0):

The `$('#hidden-form').css('display', 'block')` is to set the value of `display`. To checked it, use `$('#hidden-form').css('display')`. So your code should be:

```
( $(window).width() <= 767 && $('#hidden-form').css('display') == 'block' )
```

Comment: So this is what I have now, I am still seeing the same problem however. The function is canceled even on desktop/tablet.